# How do I delete Youtube Channel Art from Page (not Profile)?

Tags: youtube, picasa, youtube-channels

Hello I am trying to delete old channel art. The one suggestion I found was to go to https://picasaweb.google.com/home. That doesn't work for me. That shows my profile and blog photos, not my 'page' photos.

I did figure out how to get to my source image folder for my page, but it only shows scrapbook photos and profile image photos:

[image]

What I want to get to is the other photos, as shown as available if I click:
Manage This Page / Edit / Posts / Photo / Your Google Photos

[image]

The weird thing is that I was once able to get them through https://picasaweb.google.com/pageID

I tried https://picasaweb.google.com/PageID/YoutubeChannelArt, but that didn't work.

I want to delete those Youtube Channel Art photos. They are eating away at my storage space!

HALP!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if you still need a solution for this or if you figured it out yourself since then, but I stumbled upon your question while searching on Google for a solution to the same problem. Needless to say, I was annoyed when I saw that the question was unanswered.

I've found the solution while searching online for a bit longer, though.

You will have to give your Google+ page its own login and password. [This](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.ca/2014/03/set-login-id-and-password-for-a-google-plus-page.html) is the page I've found that explained how to do it.

Then you can log onto Picasa Web as usual, except instead of logging in with your regular gmail account, you will login with the new login and password that was given to your Google+ page. You should now be able to access every photo and photo album on your Google+ page.

This was a huge pain for me because it had several random duplicate photo albums that I wished to get rid of and I had to jump through 50 hoops to finally get to delete these albums and the duplicate pictures, but it works. Why they removed the option to manage your photo albums directly from Google+, I have no idea.